# Facebook Local Currency Payments Breaking Changes Using Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-payment-dialog

While migrating for the Local Currency Payments Breaking Changes

after we post (product => 'http:...', type => 'charge', status => 'completed', test => '1', to => NN, from => NN, access_token => '123..xyz') to https://graph.facebook.com/[NN]/payments
we get this result: 
    [error] => Array
        (
            [message] => (#3) App must be on whitelist
            [type] => OAuthException
            [code] => 3
        )

in: **Apps > [App Name] > Advanced > Security > Server IP Whitelist** we entered the server ip address but we still get the same error

Comment: _App must be on whitelist_ has nothing to do with the server IP whitelist – it means that you are trying to use an API feature that is (not yet) publicly available, but only for apps that are on a whitelist with Facebook.

Comment: How can we make our app to be on whitelist with Facebook?